# How to load an image in the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to insert an image in the mailer that is sent to the user. I tried this

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'vamsi@digifutura.com'

    def welcome_email(email)
        email_with_name = %('gates', <gvpmahesh@gmail.com>)
        attachments.inline['truck.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s + '/app/assets/images/truck.png'}")
        mail(to: email, subject: 'Look at the truck2')
    end

end
```

Here is the view

```
This is an experiment to send an email with image
<%= image_tag attachments['truck.png'].url %>
```

Here is the controller

```
class MailersController < ApplicationController
  def email_send
    UserMailer.welcome_email('gvpm1994@gmail.com').deliver_now
  end

  def show
    render plain: 'OK'
    email_send
  end
end
```

But the above code sends an attachment, but I am seeking to render the image along with the email text.

[image: this is the outcome]

Comment: One possible way, is to have img tag pointed to imgur or something, but I want the images to come from assets

Comment: `File.read("#{root_url.to_s + '/assets/images/truck.png'}")` should work!

Comment: If you the `image` you are trying to serve is going to be part of your `assets` folder, have you tried `image_url "truck.png"` ? Refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url for more info.

Comment: @Dharam Still it sending an attachment. And the image is not loading.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli But it is sending an attachment, image is not rendering, Check the screenshot

Comment: Refer to the source of the email. If you are sending it to gmail, you can click 'Show Original' to see the source. And see what is being rendered at the place of the image. Is it the full url or just the path?

Comment: <img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8vobwAphSZLhhRfXkG4Cy_8kY65XAcb3YXeA5pJdZkWOu1xOxJLCQzkzstLKIZTs0MfdT1vZtM8Xhi72x6TVBCns9FVA6SrDafsU41NEG3xXRH7wN2Ksqgv9OHzNLAnDM8aHEWdABdYC2oyd3BOhxtDeeRAqTa3P=s0-d-e1-ft#http:///assets/delivery/truck-d5b47ff1a8f70480d20db9d192eb4d38cc7b1eeeafb435c3df3357db7a3bbad1.png" alt="Truck d5b47ff1a8f70480d20db9d192eb4d38cc7b1eeeafb435c3df3357db7a3bbad1" class="CToWUd"> this is the image tag

Comment: As far as I understood, you want a self-contained email, with images and everything. May I ask why? Having email load image from your web app makes emails much much lighter (saves your processing power and bandwidth). Also, in the case of unopened email, all this bundling would have happened in vain.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Client requirement just cannot say no :( . So is there any way that I can overcome this? Rails guides also does not show info on this

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem

```
<%= image_tag attachments.inline["truck.png"].url %>
```

Comment: Seems like these guys have a bug in docs
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html ... look they missed `inline` in the views

Comment: You can send them a PR with the fix and become rails contributor :)

Answer (score -1):

Do changes like this :

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'vamsi@digifutura.com'

    def welcome_email(email)
        email_with_name = %('gates', <gvpmahesh@gmail.com>)
        attachments.inline['truck.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s + '/assets/images/truck.png'}")
        @truck_url = "#{Rails.root.to_s + '/assets/images/truck.png'"
        mail(to: email, subject: 'Look at the truck2')
    end

end
```

**view :**

```
This is an experiment to send an email with image
<img src="#{@truck_url}"></img>
```

Comment: @gates can you confirm you want to send an atatchment or just show an image in the mail ?